# Chrome extension to determine how saturated a product is on aliexpress.com

Tags: chrome, cloud-storage, ecommerce, business-intelligence, research

My sister is getting started in drop-shipping. She has the set up. She has asked me to find out a way to see if a product is untapped or over-saturated on aliexpress.com. I would like to offer her a solution. She is looking for a chrome extension. I would really admire a recommendation.